# Store mixin in mixin's parameter with SASS

Tags: html, sass

I have a code which builds up the required styles with query in the class. What I want to earn:

```
@mixin views ($mixinToApply) {
  @include $mixinToApply;
  &-from-tablet {
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      @include $mixinToApply;
    }
  }
  &-from-desktop {
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
      @include $mixinToApply;
    }
  }
}

$colors: (
  red, blue, purple
);

@mixin setColors {
  @each $color in $colors {
    &-#{$color} {
      color: $color;
    }
  }
}

.colors { @include setColors }

/*
it will set the colors initially, but if I want to change colors
if the window reaches the breakpoint, we'd need something like this
*/

.colors { @include views ($setColors) }
```

It could save a lot of time, if we have multiple mixins. They'd only need to be processed through `views`.

Any idea how to reach the above effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `@content;` to pass some additional rules to mixin:

```
@mixin views () {

  @content;

  &-from-tablet {
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      @content;
    }
  }

  &-from-desktop {
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
      @content;
    }
  }
}

$colors: (
  red, blue, purple
);

@mixin setColors {
  @each $color in $colors {
    &-#{$color} {
      color: $color;
    }
  }
}

.colors { @include setColors }

/*
it will set the colors initially, but if I want to change colors
if the window reaches the breakpoint, we'd need something like this
*/

@mixin mixinToApply() {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.colors {
  @include views () {
    @include mixinToApply;
  }
}
```

Css output:

```
.colors-red {
  color: red;
}

.colors-blue {
  color: blue;
}

.colors-purple {
  color: purple;
}

/*
it will set the colors initially, but if I want to change colors
if the window reaches the breakpoint, we'd need something like this
*/
.colors {
  font-size: 14px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .colors-from-tablet {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
  .colors-from-desktop {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```

But why do you need the same styles for all breakpoints?

[Demo](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/fd4003278f3c5d64d21e2b6d8d79551e)

Comment: Amazing solution, thanks a lot! Because if I want two elements, one with red color, and one with blue but just from tablet, if I defined the first element's class as `color-red`, and the second one with `color-from-tablet-red`, I'll reach what I want. `.color` just applies if it's alone.